# How to pass an :id when creating a new instance in form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 2 models, Lanzadera and Addict.

```
Lanzadera has_many :addicts
Addict belongs_to :lanzadera
```

I have a list of Lanzaderas with a "Sign up" button next to them, that will render the Addict new form.

The user will then fill out a form with the Addict attributes, and that addict should be listed in that particular lanzadera. So, it's all about listing addicts in lanzaderas.

Everything looks great, I can see `lanzadera_id` in the logs, but when I say `@lanzadera.addicts.count` it will put `0`. That means, addicts are being created but are not being assigned to it's lanzadera.

`lanzadera_id` is being permitted in `addict_params` in the controller strong parameters.

My question is, how can I pass `lanzadera_id` in my form when creating a new `Addict`, so that the addict gets listed within that `Lanzadera`?

```
Started POST "/lanzaderas/1/addicts" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-10 19:25:41 +0200
Processing by AddictsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"mJ7pl2xsjhwhdGM2RZBDA+fmD75tpZcsPIaeSwYaBhE=", "addict"=>{"name"=>"Kike", "email"=>"kikeisasi@gmail.com", "city"=>"65", "postal"=>"56478", "street"=>"Aiboa 19, 4", "lanzadera_id"=>""}, "commit"=>"Crear Addict", "lanzadera_id"=>"1"}
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.7ms)  INSERT INTO "addicts" ("city", "created_at", "email", "name", "postal", "street", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7) RETURNING "id"  [["city", "65"], ["created_at", Thu, 10 Jul 2014 17:25:41 UTC +00:00], ["email", "kikeisasi@gmail.com"], ["name", "Kike"], ["postal", 56478], ["street", "Aiboa 19, 4"], ["updated_at", Thu, 10 Jul 2014 17:25:41 UTC +00:00]]
```

Comment: You're going to want to look into `fields_for` and `accepts_nested_attributes_for`.  Those are the rails helper which will build a correctly structured form which will include that information and the model method which allows this to happen automatically on the server side, respectively.

Comment: Ill take a look at it! Thanks for responding @ABMagil

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are missing the `landazera_id` in the Addicts table in your database. When it begins the `INSERT INTO` line it doesn't list the id as one of the columns. If you haven't, make sure 'landazera_id' migrated into the table. Rails doesn't do this automatically based on your `has_many`, `belongs_to` associations (or at least I've never figured out how to make it automatic) so you'll have to make the migration yourself.

```
rails g migration add_landazera_id_to_addicts landazera_id:integer
```

Check the migration in your text editor to make sure it generated correctly. It should include:

```
def change
    add_column :addicts, :landazera_id, :integer
end
```

Comment: I do have t.integer  "lanzadera_id" in my Addicts table... Thats why I don't understand why lanzadera_id is not INSERTED INTO Addict... should it do it automatically or do I have to put a hidden input or something in order to pass it? @nucleogenesis